# SQLAlchemy: ordered collection without relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use the [ordering list extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html) from SQLAlchemy to order *all* entities of a collection. So e.g. I have:

```
class Job(Base):
    position = Column(Integer)
```

And when I `session.add(Job(position=2))` all already existing jobs are updated with the correct postion.

Example:

```
Job |  Pos
----------
 A      1 
 B      2
```

Then adding C with position 2 (automatically) results in

```
Job |  Pos
----------
 A      1 
 C      2
 B      3
```

Edit: Right now I see two approaches to solve that. The first would be fixing the order manually with events or the second one by using a helper class with an ordered relationship after all. But what I am looking for is a more pure realization, reusing existing code (ordering list) without the overhead of a helper class.

Comment: The problem is that you do not have a single point where the list of jobs is kept, do you? Normally you would do something like `session.querys(Job).order_by(Job.position).all()`. If you now add a new job to the sessin like you say above, should it then magically appear in the return of every query you ran on it? You will need some kind of single entry point that manages this. Or did I miss something from the question?

Comment: @javex The database is the point where the list of jobs is kept...

Comment: Exactly. But that did not answer my question: Where *in your python code* should this magical list be updated? Where is that located?

Comment: That doesn't matter... Or what's your point?

Comment: You want this list to be automatically ordered. But where is that list? If it is in the database, just query the database again and it will be ordered. But if it is in python code, it is most likely a simple list returned from a query. I see your problem in the design/approach you take. Give a code example and say where you want to have the new element applied and what's not working the way you'd like it to.

Comment: OK, you clearly missed the point from the question. The key is that `position` of every element in the collection has to be updated after each INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE. So it is not the case that you "just query the database again and it will be ordered".

Comment: Ahhh now I see. Sorry for missing that. In that case, I'd use `after_insert` and friends events: Use [Mapper Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents) to execute updating queries after you update the position. I don't know of any implementation that does what you want but writing your own should be easy. Just pay attention to possible recursion.